# ViewPager и Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Пишу свой календарь понедельный для приложения. Создал фрагмент, который добавляю в `ViewPager` через свой адаптер с помощью `newInstance()`. В фрагменте есть `GridView`, который заполняется датами в зависимости от номера страницы. При выделении ячейки `GridView` получаю одерживаемое ячейки. Но если выделить на одной странице `GridView` ячейку, потом перелистнуть на другую и выделить ячейку там, то выделение сохраняется на обоих страницах.

Задача состоит в том, чтобы при выделении даты на другой странице календаря, предыдущие выделения  пропадали, не пойму как это сделать.

Класс в котором `Viewpager` и адаптер

```
public class ServiceMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    static final int PAGE_COUNT = 9;
    int pos;

    ViewPager CalendarPager;
    CalendarPagerAdapter _CalendarPagerAdapter;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_service_menu);

        CalendarPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.CalendarPager);

        _CalendarPagerAdapter = new CalendarPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        CalendarPager.setAdapter(_CalendarPagerAdapter);
        CalendarPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(9);


        CalendarPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                pos =position;
             //Log.d(TAG, ""+pos);

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                                       int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            }
        });


    }

    public void onClick(View view) {
        Log.d(TAG, ""+_CalendarPagerAdapter.getItemId(pos));
        CalendarFragmentPager.newInstance(pos).ClearC();

    }

}

class CalendarPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
      static final String TAG = "myLogs";
      private long baseId = 0;


    public CalendarPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

      @Override
      public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
          Fragment fragment = (Fragment) super.instantiateItem(container, position);
          registeredFragments.put(position, fragment);
          return fragment;
      }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return CalendarFragmentPager.newInstance(position);
    }


    public Fragment getRegisteredFragment(int position){
        return registeredFragments.get(position);
    }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int position) {
          // give an ID different from position when position has been changed
          return baseId + position;
      }



      @Override
      public int getCount() {
        return PAGE_COUNT;
      }
}
```

Сам Фрагмент

```
public class CalendarFragmentPager extends Fragment {

    static final String ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER = "arg_page_number";
    static final String TAG = "myLogs";
    TextView tvPage;


    int pageNumber;
    int StartPosition=0;

    Calendar calendar;
    GridView CalendarGrid;
    CustomCalendarAdapter _CustomCalendarAdapter;

     static CalendarFragmentPager newInstance(int page) {
        CalendarFragmentPager _CalendarFragmentPager = new CalendarFragmentPager();
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER, page);
        _CalendarFragmentPager.setArguments(arguments);
        return _CalendarFragmentPager;
    }

    public  CalendarFragmentPager(){

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        pageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARGUMENT_PAGE_NUMBER);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.calendar_fragment, null);

        final String[] DateArray = {"", "", "", "", "", "", ""};
        String Month = "";
        String DayName;
        final Date CurrentDate;
        Date newDate;
        calendar = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        CurrentDate = calendar.getTime();

        switch (pageNumber) {
            case 0:
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i);
                    newDate = calendar.getTime(); 
                    DayName = (String) DateFormat.format("dd\nEE", newDate);
                    Month = (String) DateFormat.format("LLLL", newDate);
                    DateArray[i] = DayName;
                    calendar.setTime(CurrentDate); 
                }
                break;
            case 1:
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i + 7); 
                    newDate = calendar.getTime();
                    DayName = (String) DateFormat.format("dd\nEE", newDate);
                    Month = (String) DateFormat.format("LLLL", newDate);
                    DateArray[i] = DayName;
                    calendar.setTime(CurrentDate);
                }
                break;
            case 2:
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i + 14); 
                    newDate = calendar.getTime(); 
                    DayName = (String) DateFormat.format("dd\nEE", newDate);
                    Month = (String) DateFormat.format("LLLL", newDate);
                    DateArray[i] = DayName;
                    calendar.setTime(CurrentDate); 
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i + 21); 
                    newDate = calendar.getTime(); 
                    DayName = (String) DateFormat.format("dd\nEE", newDate);
                    Month = (String) DateFormat.format("LLLL", newDate);
                    DateArray[i] = DayName;
                    calendar.setTime(CurrentDate); 
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i + 28); 
                    newDate = calendar.getTime(); 
                    DayName = (String) DateFormat.format("dd\nEE", newDate);
                    Month = (String) DateFormat.format("LLLL", newDate);
                    DateArray[i] = DayName;
                    calendar.setTime(CurrentDate); 
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i + 35); 
                    newDate = calendar.getTime(); 
                    DayName = (String) DateFormat.format("dd\nEE", newDate);
                    Month = (String) DateFormat.format("LLLL", newDate);
                    DateArray[i] = DayName;
                    calendar.setTime(CurrentDate); 
                }
                break;
            case 6:
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i + 42);
                    newDate = calendar.getTime(); 
                    DayName = (String) DateFormat.format("dd\nEE", newDate);
                    Month = (String) DateFormat.format("LLLL", newDate);
                    DateArray[i] = DayName;
                    calendar.setTime(CurrentDate); 
                }
                break;
            case 7:
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i + 49);
                    newDate = calendar.getTime(); 
                    DayName = (String) DateFormat.format("dd\nEE", newDate);
                    Month = (String) DateFormat.format("LLLL", newDate);
                    DateArray[i] = DayName;
                    calendar.setTime(CurrentDate); 
                }
                break;
            case 8:
                for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, i + 56); 
                    newDate = calendar.getTime(); 
                    DayName = (String) DateFormat.format("dd\nEE", newDate);
                    Month = (String) DateFormat.format("LLLL", newDate);
                    DateArray[i] = DayName;
                    calendar.setTime(CurrentDate); 
                }
                break;
        }


        tvPage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvPage);
        tvPage.setText(Month.toUpperCase());
        CalendarGrid = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.CalendarGrid);
        _CustomCalendarAdapter= new CustomCalendarAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                 DateArray);
        CalendarGrid.setChoiceMode(GridView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        CalendarGrid.setAdapter(_CustomCalendarAdapter);
        CalendarGrid.setNumColumns(7);

        final String temp =(String) DateFormat.format("dd\nEE", CurrentDate);
          if(_CustomCalendarAdapter.getItem(0).equals(temp)) {
              CalendarGrid.setItemChecked(0, true);
           }


           CalendarGrid.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v,
                                    int position, long id) {
            }

           });


        return view;

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: " + pageNumber);
    }



    public void ClearC()
    {
        CalendarGrid.clearChoices();
    }

}
```

Comment: Методы и переменные именуются с маленькой буквы. У вас с Большой и код от этого почти нечитаем. Также без сообщения об ошибке и указания строки возникновения помочь вам почти нельзя.

Comment: Спасибо большое за замечание учту и отрефракторю. Дело даже не в ошибке, я не могу понять как вообще это сделать.

Comment: Вы можете сохранить ссылки на фрагменты в адаптере и потом вызывать методы фрагментов для снятия выделения

Comment: Юрий Можно пример кода плс. как сохранить то эти ссылки ?

Comment: Заведите в адаптере List<Fragment> frags = new ArrayList<>(); Потом в getItem перед возвратом фрагмента поместите его в этот список

Comment: Спасибо большое. А метод вызывать через  frags ? На яве сижу 2 недели всего.

Comment: Ну,. Да. Сделайте гетер в адаптере для списка фрагментов и вызывайте методы. Главное не сохранять умершие фрагменты